# Cookies...Http POST doesn't correctly work, why?

Tags: java, cookies, post, httpclient

Probably this is often problem, but I can't solve it.
I need to automaticallly fill out some fields on the web form, which is given from server.
I use Apache HttpClient to make more easy my life)
By now, one can consider my steps to acheive the aim:

  1. I have not certificate to http://trac.edgewall.org/ so I download this software and install locally and at finish I'll have to create NewTicket.

  2. I locally use Trac without any SSL(SSL tunnel). (It's not difficult to change my program to be able to use HTTPS).

  3. By now, I can authenticate and perform GET request, but I can't perform POST request

  4. For instance: I perform GET request to the
  http://localhost:8000/tracenvir/newticket
  .
  This (~/newticket) page looks as following:
  http://s04.radikal.ru/i177/0912/cb/d43971cebc02.png
  And as response I have : (part of it)

  "input type="text" id="field-summary" name="field_summary" size="70" "

  "textarea id="field-description" name="field_description" class="wikitext" rows="10" cols="68"/textarea"'

  5. So, I write this:

```
        int status = 0;
        int cookLength=0;
        Cookie[] cookies = null;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
        HttpState initialState = new HttpState();
        client.setState(initialState);

        //**********//
        //**Log in**//
        //**********//

        GetMethod login = new GetMethod("http://localhost:8000/tracenvir/login");
        client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("rauch", "qwert"));
        login.setDoAuthentication(true);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/rauch/NetBeansProjects/jssecacerts");

        try {
            status = client.executeMethod(login);

        System.out.println("response code = "+status);
        cookies = client.getState().getCookies();
        cookLength = cookies.length;

        for(int i=0;i (less than) cookLength;i++) {
            System.out.println(cookies[i].toString());
        }
        login.releaseConnection();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
        //*********************//
        //**Create New Ticket**//
        //*********************//

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8000/tracenvir/newticket");

        NameValuePair[] data = {
            new NameValuePair("field-summary","second error"),
            new NameValuePair("field-descryption","Some stupid descryption..."),
            new NameValuePair("field-type","defect"),
            new NameValuePair("field-priority","major"),
            new NameValuePair("field-version","1.0"),
            new NameValuePair("field-owner","moscow server"),
            new NameValuePair("submit","create ticket"),
        };


        //post.setRequestBody(data);
        post.addParameters(data);
        post.addRequestHeader("Referer","http://localhost:8000/tracenvir/login");
        for(int i=0;i (less than) cookLength;i++) {
            initialState.addCookie(cookies[i]);
        }
        client.setState(initialState);


        try {
            status = client.executeMethod(post);

        System.out.println("response code = "+status);

        byte[] buf = new byte[10];
        int r=0;
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(post.getResponseBodyAsStream());

        while((r = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
            System.out.write(buf, 0, r);
        }
        post.releaseConnection();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And I have this:

  400 Error: Bad Request

  Missing or invalid form token. Do you have cookies enabled?

What's wrong?

  As response on GET request I get this:
    response code = 200
    trac_auth=38144ec2830678183afebf0b14c51721
    trac_form_token=e9648f17987551b8f97e1953

Probably I nedd change this:

  client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47972

I think above link will help u on this topic. its provide video also.. i hope your query will be solved

http://www.formautofill.com/

This site will give you a software which will provide auto form filler. provided by microsoft.

Comment: No...I must fill out the form with POST method ONLY.
Thanks a lot, but it's useless for me...

Comment: ok. i will try to get the answer. because. this think i did. 1 year ago. when i was developin one toolbar . which is on this base. .. ok

Comment: oh. sorry .. its. thing. not think.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This below link is about post method . i think it might help u.

http://www.willmaster.com/library/manage-forms/automatic-form-submission-to-a-cgi-program.php

give me reply. if it doesn't.

Comment: This article is about JScript only.
I read rfc about POST http method and saw some examples, but it isn't work correctly about me.